# Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'ApplicationDbContext' has not been registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, .net-5, dbcontext

I get an error at the starting of the application:

> An error occurred while trying to connect to the DB.(Myproj.Web.Program)
> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Myproj.Infrastructure.Data.ApplicationDbContext' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
> at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
> at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
> at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
> at Myproj.Web.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\proj\myproj\src\Myproj.Web\Program.cs:line 45

here is my Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static bool DatabaseUnavailable = false;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(config).CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("MyProg Application Starting Up");

            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>(); // ERROR
```

It seems that when the application attempts to resolve the `ApplicationDbContext` from the IoC container (Autofac in this case), it's not finding it. This could be because it wasn't registered properly, or the registration was overridden or missing.

Here is the code:

1. **Program.cs**: This is where the error originates from, specifically at:

```cs
var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

The program is trying to get an instance of `ApplicationDbContext` from the DI container but fails because it's not registered.

2. **StartupSetup.cs**: This is where the `ApplicationDbContext` is being added to the `IServiceCollection`.

```cs
public static class StartupSetup
{
    public static void AddDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString) =>
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                providerOptions =>
                {
                    providerOptions
                        .EnableRetryOnFailure(
                            maxRetryCount: 5, 
                            maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                            errorNumbersToAdd: null)
                        .UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
                });
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();

    // ... rest of the code
```

3. **Startup.cs**: This is where the services are configured, and it's crucial to check if `AddDbContext` is called correctly. I 've called:

```cs
string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyWebApp");
services.AddDbContext(connectionString);
```

This should add `ApplicationDbContext` to the `IServiceCollection`. However, this doesn't guarantee that it's registered within Autofac.

4. **Program.cs and Startup.cs**: I am using Autofac as DI container, and there are specific configurations where I integrate Autofac with ASP.NET Core:

```cs
.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
```

and in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterModule(new DefaultInfrastructureModule(_env.EnvironmentName == "Development",
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    // ... rest of the code
}
```

How can I ensure that the `ApplicationDbContext` is correctly registered within Autofac's `ContainerBuilder` too?

Here bellow the Autofac module definition:

```
public class DefaultInfrastructureModule : Module
    {
        private readonly bool _isDevelopment = false;
        private readonly List<Assembly> _assemblies = new List<Assembly>();

        public DefaultInfrastructureModule(bool isDevelopment, Assembly callingAssembly = null)
        {
            _isDevelopment = isDevelopment;
            var coreAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IUserResolverService));
            var infrastructureAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Repository));
            _assemblies.Add(coreAssembly);
            _assemblies.Add(infrastructureAssembly);
            if (callingAssembly != null)
            {
                _assemblies.Add(callingAssembly);
            }
        }

        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            if (_isDevelopment)
            {
                RegisterDevelopmentOnlyDependencies(builder);
            }
            else
            {
                RegisterProductionOnlyDependencies(builder);
            }
            RegisterCommonDependencies(builder);
        }

        private void RegisterCommonDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            //var infrastructureAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(EfRepository));
            builder
                .RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assemblies.ToArray())
                .PublicOnly()
                .Where(t =>
                t.Name.EndsWith("Repository") ||
                t.Name.EndsWith("Factory") ||
                t.Name.EndsWith("Service") ||
                t.Name.EndsWith("Generator") ||
                false
                )
                .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            //builder.RegisterType<EfRepository>().As<IRepository>()
            //    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder
                .RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>()
                .As<IHttpContextAccessor>()
                .SingleInstance();

            builder
                .RegisterType<Mediator>()
                .As<IMediator>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(context =>
            {
                var c = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                return t => c.Resolve(t);
            });

            var mediatrOpenTypes = new[]
            {
                typeof(IRequestHandler<,>),
                typeof(IRequestExceptionHandler<,,>),
                typeof(IRequestExceptionAction<,>),
                typeof(INotificationHandler<>),
            };

            foreach (var mediatrOpenType in mediatrOpenTypes)
            {
                builder
                .RegisterAssemblyTypes(_assemblies.ToArray())
                .AsClosedTypesOf(mediatrOpenType)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
            }

            builder.RegisterType<EmailSender>().As<IEmailSender>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }

        private void RegisterDevelopmentOnlyDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // TODO: Add development only services
        }

        private void RegisterProductionOnlyDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            // TODO: Add production only services
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you using Autofac when .Net Core by default provides DI Container?

Comment: @AjayManagaon I don't know anymore, it should be probably a reason that some advanced feature wasn't available in .net default

Comment: There's both too much and not enough code here. Too much: for a minimal repro, remove all the extra registrations that don't have anything to do with this. If the `AddDbContext` is there the context is added, that's all you need. (Also try that in your program!) Not enough: the sample doesn't show how you're actually creating the host (`CreateHostBuilder`) so we don't know if that's doing something weird. Try making a minimal repro on your end. No logging, no extras, just the context registration and Autofac and that's it. You may solve your own problem, or you'll know what to post here.

Answer (score 0):

Finally ended up to register manually the DbContext

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterModule(new DefaultInfrastructureModule(_env.EnvironmentName == "Development",
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

    // added this
    builder.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

and the error is gone